# CSS3 expandable search box does not work properly with placeholder

Tags: html, css, transition, placeholder

I want to hide placeholder if search icon is not clicked. Is this even possible? If this is possible, than how i can fix this problem?

**HTML**

```
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="search" placeholder="some text" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input { outline: none; }
input[type=search] {
    font-family: inherit; 
    font-size: 100%; 
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}

input::-webkit-search-decoration, input::-webkit-search-cancel-button
   { display: none; }

input[type=search] { 
    background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px; 
    border:none; 
    height:35px; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s; 
    transition: all .5s; }


#demo-2 input[type=search] {
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
    background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
    width: 626px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: auto;
}


#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder { color:red; }
#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:red; }
```

Demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dW92N/2/)

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for any of answers.

Comment: You should post the relevant code here, not just your HTML.

Comment: So you wan't 'some text' to not show up unless the icon is clicked?

Comment: YES! Exactly! And when icon is clicked, than placeholder should be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this adding `onfocus` and `onblur` attributes to the `input`:

```
<input type="search" onfocus="placeholder='some text'" onblur="placeholder=''" />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dW92N/3/

Comment: heh, thanks :) i also find answer by myself, but i think your answer ir more easier. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i found answer myself..

```
#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
#demo-2 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:red }
#demo-2 input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:red; }
```